# Display Qbytearray as Image in QT 5.12.9 version

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, opencv-mat

I am reading the `QByteArray` using `QTcpSocket` and converting the array into the cvMat image. to display the image using imshow().but i am getting gray image.
code is as follows.

```
//array ->QBytearray (received from socket) 
cv::Mat img,img1;
    img.cols=320;
    img.rows=240;
img = cv::Mat(240,320, CV_8UC1,array.data());
cv::cvtColor(img, img, CV_GRAY2RGB);  // 
      cv::imshow("image display",img);
      cv::waitKey(5000);
```

after cvtColour() function also its not converting into colour image.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look at `cv::Mat::convertTo`. In `cvtColor` src and dest have the same depth.

Comment: Test it with CV_8UC3

Comment: @rafix07 after changing src and destination also showing same gray image.

Comment: Please show the code that serializes and sends the image.

Comment: @Farshid616 it throws an error.   OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (scn == 1 && (dcn == 3 || dcn == 4)) in cvtColor, file /build/opencv-ys8xiq/opencv-2.4.9.1+dfsg/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp, line 3789
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  /build/opencv-ys8xiq/opencv-2.4.9.1+dfsg/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp:3789: error: (-215) scn == 1 && (dcn == 3 || dcn == 4) in function cvtColor

Aborted (core dumped)

Comment: @G.M. Image send code i have implement on linux platform using opencv c++ . ``` Mat image = imread("pk.png",0);
  int sockfd, portno, n, imgSize, IM_HEIGHT, IM_WIDTH;

 imgSize = image.total()*image.elemSize();
   n = send(sockfd, image.data,imgSize, 0);
    printf("n=%d\n",n);

    if (n < 0) error("ERROR writing to socket");
```

Comment: CV_GRAY2RGB - > COLOR_GRAY2RGB ?

Comment: @Hihikomori COLOR_GRAY2RGB its not supported.

Comment: cv::cvtColor(img, img, CV_GRAY2RGB) - copies one channel image to channels of rgb image. After converting it's still will by looking gray. You need to modify one  channel to see some color.

Comment: @Hihikomori could you please suggest how to modify one channel . I have tried many ways buts its not working. Thanks in advance

Comment: Test it with CV_8UC3 also remove cvtcolor line or change CV_GRAY2RGB with CV_BGR2RGB

Comment: @Farshid616 Throws and segmentation fault received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff73b7640 in cv::CvtColorLoop_Invoker<cv::RGB2RGB<unsigned char> >::operator()(cv::Range const&) const () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_imgproc.so.2.4

Comment: You are reading from socket grayscale image. There is no method to make it colored  back.

Answer (score 0):

This is the way to modify channels separately:

```
img = cv::Mat(240,320, CV_8UC1,array.data());
cv::Mat img1;
cv::divide(img,cv::Scalar(2),img1);
std::vector<cv::Mat> channels;
   
channels.push_back(img);
channels.push_back(img1);
channels.push_back(img);
cv::merge(channels, img);

cv::imshow("image display",img);
cv::waitKey(5000);
```

Comment: Thanks for prompt help. but there is difference between original client image and server QT image. @server side it showing in only one colour.

Comment: Is it good approach to convert the cv mat image into Qimage and then display in QT